# How to perform SQL queries and get results from QGIS python console?

Tags: qgis, postgresql, pyqgis

I'm writing a python script using QGIS API. I have to get results from postgres database table. The table has geometry field and other non-geometry fields.

I want to perform SQL queries on non-geometry fields and get results in my code. How to do this? Is there any class to do so?

I know about `QgsDataSourceURI` class but as far as I know it only gets results from geometry fields.

Comment: What is dict_cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor) ? >>> import psycopg2 >>> psycopg2.extras gives me a Traceback Traceback (most recent call last): File "<input>", line 1, in <module> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'extras'

Comment: @JochenSchwarze you were missing the import of the `extras` module, e.g. `import psycopg2.extras`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1) With PyQt4.QtSql: Gary Sherman shows how to query a spatial table in [Creating a PostgreSQL Connection From a QGIS Layer Datasource](http://pythongisbook.com/blog/2013/04/11/creating-a-postgresql-connection-from-a-qgis-layer-datasource/):

```
from PyQt4.QtSql import *
layer = iface.activeLayer()
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "testpostgis", "me", "")
uri.setDataSource("public", "teststrati", "the_geom")
# add the layer to the canvas
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "tot", "postgres")
# now query the table
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL");
db.setHostName(uri.host())
db.setDatabaseName(uri.database())
db.setPort(int(uri.port()))
db.setUserName(uri.username())
db.setPassword(uri.password())
db.open()
# query the table
query = db.exec_("""select * from teststrati""")
query.next()
query.value(0)
130
# etc read the documentation of QtSQL
```

And you can open all the other tables/views (spatial or non spatial) similarly:

```
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL")
db.setHostName("localhost")
db.setPort(5432)
# non spatial table or view
db.setDatabaseName("people")
db.setUserName("me")
db.setPassword("")
query = QSqlQuery(db)
query.exec_("select * from people;")
# etc.
```

2) Or you can use the standard Python module for PostgreSQL/PostGIS: [Psycopg2](http://pythonhosted.org//psycopg2/):

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='testpostgis'host='localhost' user='me'")
cur = conn.cursor()
sql = """SELECT "DIP_DIR","DIP", ST_AsGeoJSON(the_geom) from teststrati;"""
cur.execute(sql)
result = cur.fetchone()
print result
(130, 30, u'{"type":"Point","coordinates":[272070.600040999997873,155389.387920000008307]}')
```

With a non spatial table or view and the result as a dictionary:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='testpostgis'host='localhost' user='me'")  
dict_cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
dict_cur.execute("""SELECT * from people;""")
rec = dict_cur.fetchone()
rec.keys()
['name', 'id']
rec.values()
('Jon Doe',1)
# etc read the documentation of the module
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what DB you are using. If it is Postgresql, you have to install and import psycopg2 the [PostgreSQL + Python library](http://initd.org/psycopg/)

to install use:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

or:

```
easy_install install psycopg2
```

Follow [this tutorial](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Psycopg2_Tutorial), or else, for the basics

Comment: QGIS has PGSql python library and there is no need to download it. Just to say. I know this answer is 5 years old but I am commenting on it since the question is still relevent and people come here as I did.

Comment: @ImanNia you meant QtSql, right?