# Connecting QGIS, SpatiaLite and Python?

Tags: qgis, python, sql, spatialite

I am trying to connect with python code, QGIS and Spatialite, to do SQL query. I have read some tips and I tried with this code, but no add anything.

Any Idea?

```
uri=QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setDatabase('C:\Users\pr\Desktop\GIS.sqlite')
schema=' '
table ='ambi'
geom_column= 'geom'
uri.setDataSource(schema, table, geom_column)
display_name=('prueba')
vlayer=QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), display_name, 'spatialite')
```

---

Finally I have put this:

```
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setDatabase('C:/Desktop/GIS.sqlite')
schema = ''
table = 'PV'
geom_column = 'geom'
uri.setDataSource(schema, table, geom_column)
display_name = 'PV'
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), display_name, 'spatialite')
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName(uri.database())
db.open()
query=db.exec_("""select * from PV where pk=1 """)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

But It adds the complete shape and I want only add, the PV with pk=1.
Could you tell me why it is?

Comment: Try forward slashes in your database path.

Comment: Or try putting an 'r' in front of your path like this: `r'C:\Users\pr\Desktop\GIS.sqlite'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a doubt about your expectations

**If it's doing SQL query on a SQlite/Spatialite DB within QGIS**

Select the layer that use SQlite as a source, then do

```
# Import QtSql function(s)
from PyQt4.QtSql import QSqlDatabase

# Get selected layer
layer = iface.activeLayer()
# Get file path
uri = QgsDataSourceURI(layer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri())
# Create DB connexion to do SQL 
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE");
# Reuse the path to DB to set database name
db.setDatabaseName(uri.database())
# Open the connection
db.open()
# query the table
query = db.exec_("""select * from your_table""")
# Play with results (not efficient, just for demo)
while query.next():
    values = []
    record = query.record()
    for index in range(record.count()):
        # We exclude the geometry to join attributes data
        if not isinstance(record.value(index), QByteArray):
            values.append(str(record.value(index)))
    print ';'.join(values)
```

It was mainly inspired by [this topic](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86707/how-to-perform-sql-queries-and-get-results-from-qgis-python-console) but applied to SQLite/Spatialite

To really use Spatialite (in fact an extension you load in SQLite) and not only SQLite, you can replace `QSQLITE` with `QSPATIALITE`.
Then you can see if extension has been loaded with:

```
query = db.exec_("""SELECT sqlite_version(), spatialite_version()""")
query.next()
print query.value(0), query.value(1)
```

**If it's just displaying the layer from Python**

If you want to add the layer, don't forget after

```
vlayer=QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), display_name, 'spatialite')
```

to add it with:

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

A shortcut to do the same operation in one is:

```
iface.addVectorLayer(uri.uri(), display_name, 'spatialite')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
uri.setDataSource(schema, table, geom_column,"pk=1")
```

The 4th parameter (optioonal) in setDataSource is  a sql WHERE

Comment: It might help to provide some more context, or a reference.